# How do I combine conditions in where clause for two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, where-clause

I have a simple table `numInfo` with two integer columns say `col1`, `col2`. Now I want to compare them to a number so I will write a query like this :

```
select * from numInfo where col1 < 26 OR col2 <26
```

Is it possible to combine the two conditions as :

```
select * from numInfo where (col1 or col2) < 26
```

the above query gives me an error, So I just want to know how do I combine the conditions into one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to combine the conditions for `<` in a pithy expression.

If it were `=`, you could use `in`.  For `<>` you could use `not in`.  There is no corresponding shortcut for `<`.  You cannot even use `least()`/`greatest()`, because SQL Server does not support these functions.

Answer (score 0):

You would need:

```
select * from numInfo where (col1 < 26 or col2 < 26);
```

Comment: this does not help, I dont want to write the number 26 twice in my condition.

Comment: You will need to conform to language requirements, regardless.